# Viewing video feed from WebRTC in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, video-streaming

Here is the HTML code

```
<video ref={videos}  autoPlay ></video>

   <Button onClick={() => 
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then((mediaStream) => {

  videos.srcObject = mediaStream;
  videos.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    videos.play();
  };
}
)}>Record</Button>
```

JS

```
const videos = createRef(null);
```

**Error**

*Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot add property srcObject, object is not extensible*

```
 353 |    <Button onClick={() => 
  354 | navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}).then((mediaStream) => {
  355 | 
> 356 |   videos.srcObject= mediaStream;
  357 |   videos.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
  358 |     videos.play();
  359 |   };
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the DOM element, `videos.current`. Please read [the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create a ref to the video element, you must use the `video.current` property to access the DOM element. Your code should look like this:

```
<video ref={videos}  autoPlay ></video>
   <Button onClick={() => 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    .then((mediaStream) => {
      videos.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
      videos.current.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      videos.current.play();
      };
    }
    )}>Record</Button>
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: This should work, I saw the ```  . current ``` but I thought it was for only text inputs

Comment: @RaphaelInyang, check docs) https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I wasn't at home, to confirm its credibility, I'll mark it once I confirm it